# Spring http request validation with anotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I am trying to implement validation of incoming http request in spring boot app.
I was following these instructions:
https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-validate-request-body-in-spring-boot/
but I don't get response like stated in article.

I am getting exception in my console though: `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver: ... DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: default message [must be a well-formed email address]]`

Process is stopped based on set constraint (email formating, obviously), but I don't get http response messages, just `Bad Request`.

This is my controller:

```
    @RestController
    @Validated
    @RequestMapping(path = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public class UserController {

            @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        
                User createdUser = userService.createUser(user);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
            }
    }
```

And this is entity :

```
    @Entity
    @Builder
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class User {
        
        @Email
        private String email;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to mention that for me the provided link (https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-validate-request-body-in-spring-boot/) didn't work somehow...

Now to your question. As I see it, in order to archive this you'd have to create a validator first and then you could continue with something line this (not your example but it should help):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> acceptData(@Valid @RequestBody Data data, Errors errors, 
    @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE) String language) {
    stringValueValidator.validate(language, data, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createErrorString(errors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @ControllerAdvice and create your own response Object for representing not valid arguments. Example below will return all not valid arguments with its messages.

```
  @ControllerAdvice
  public class ExceptionHandlerClass extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                              HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> validationList = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream().map(fieldError->fieldError.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ExceptionObject(false,validationList), status);
} }
```